# Export only one page from a PDF file to PNG

Tags: pdf, png, ghostscript

How do I export only one page from a PDF file (e.g., page 28) to PNG?

I use this command to export all pages of PDF to PNG:

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m \
   -r400 -sOutputFile=out_%02d.png input.pdf
```

I have searched the `man gs` and the Net for any option in `gs` to do this, but I cannot find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to export specific page(s) from the pdf you need to use `-dFirstPage` and `-dLastPage` switches. You can read more about this switches here: [**How to use Ghostscript**](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#PDF_switches)

Your command will look something like:

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -r400 -dFirstPage=28 -dLastPage=28 -sOutputFile=out.png input.pdf
```

Comment: Grab a few pages into numbered png's: `gswin64c -dSAFER -sDEVICE=png16m -r400 -sPageList=2-5 -o few%d.png long.pdf`.